# How to get the CITY value from javascript file using GET or POST in HTML form [CODE ATTACHED]?

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, get

How to retrieve the CITY value using GET or POST just like STATE value can be used using $_POST['stt']?

ps: New to stack overflow, so please suggest ways to ask questions in a better way :)

```js
var state_arr = new Array("Andaman & Nicobar");

var s_a = new Array();
s_a[0] = "";
s_a[1] = " Alipur | Andaman Island | Anderson Island | Arainj-Laka-Punga | Austinabad | Bamboo Flat | Barren Island ";

function print_state(state_id) {
  // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
  var option_str = document.getElementById(state_id);
  option_str.length = 0;
  option_str.options[0] = new Option('Select State', '');
  option_str.selectedIndex = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < state_arr.length; i++) {
    option_str.options[option_str.length] = new Option(state_arr[i], state_arr[i]);
  }
}

function print_city(city_id, city_index) {
  var option_str = document.getElementById(city_id);
  option_str.length = 0; // Fixed by Julian Woods
  option_str.options[0] = new Option('Select City', '');
  option_str.selectedIndex = 0;
  var city_arr = s_a[city_index].split("|");
  for (var i = 0; i < city_arr.length; i++) {
    option_str.options[option_str.length] = new Option(city_arr[i], city_arr[i]);
  }
}

print_state("sts");
```

```html
<form>
  <select onchange="print_city('state', this.selectedIndex);" id="sts" name="stt" class="form-control" required></select>
  <select id="state" class="form-control" required></select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this you will get both city and state
give your filename in form action atribute

```js
var state_arr = new Array("Andaman & Nicobar");

var s_a = new Array();
s_a[0] = "";
s_a[1] = " Alipur | Andaman Island | Anderson Island | Arainj-Laka-Punga | Austinabad | Bamboo Flat | Barren Island ";

function print_state(state_id) {
  // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
  var option_str = document.getElementById(state_id);
  option_str.length = 0;
  option_str.options[0] = new Option('Select State', '');
  option_str.selectedIndex = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < state_arr.length; i++) {
    option_str.options[option_str.length] = new Option(state_arr[i], state_arr[i]);
  }
}

function print_city(city_id, city_index) {
  var option_str = document.getElementById(city_id);
  option_str.length = 0; // Fixed by Julian Woods
  option_str.options[0] = new Option('Select City', '');
  option_str.selectedIndex = 0;
  var city_arr = s_a[city_index].split("|");
  for (var i = 0; i < city_arr.length; i++) {
    option_str.options[option_str.length] = new Option(city_arr[i], city_arr[i]);
  }
}

print_state("sts");
```

```html
<form method="get" action="filename.html">
  <select onchange="print_city('state', this.selectedIndex);" id="sts" name="state" class="form-control" required></select>
  <select id="state" name="city" class="form-control" required></select>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```